# How to stop db.log in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, database, cli, log, debugging

How to stop the DB log i had used the CLI to stop but it is not stopping it increasing to huge file. I used the below command but it is not stopping. It is in the path **var/debug/db.log**

> bin/magento dev:query-log:disable
>
> bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this code may be help you,

Go to this path `app/etc/di.xml` and add the code :

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File"/>
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logAllQueries" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and run the `php bin/magento c:f`

And more refer link :- https://somecrazy.com/magento-2-log-database-queries/

Comment: Hello it's answer is helpful or not ??

Comment: Not working @mohit

Comment: Did you found any answer? I am facing similar issue. Tried with command, not working. file size increasing every hr alot